# Jquery minimal execution time

Tags: jquery, loading, show-hide

I've build an simple show/hide script with an loading animation. But I want the loading animation to be atleast 0,5 seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#notesunlimitedcontent').hide();
        $('#notescontent').show();

        $('a#nsetcontent').click(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#notesunlimitedcontent').hide();
            $('#notescontent').show();
            $('#loading').hide();
        });


        $('a#nusetcontent').click(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
            $('#notescontent').hide();
            $('#notesunlimitedcontent').show();
            $('#loading').hide();
        });

    });
</script>


<a id="nsetcontent" href="#">show</a>
<a id="nusetcontent" href="#">show</a>


<div id="loading">
    <img src="loading.gif"/>
</div>
<div id="notescontent">
</div>
<div id="notesunlimitedcontent">
</div>
```

So it looks like this, I don't know if I did code it right since i'm new to jquery. But I've tested it, it does show and hide the two divs but I did not see that happen with the loading div, maybe because it went to fast?

I hope someone can explain me how to let the loading time be atleast 0.5 seconds.

Thank you!

Comment: one reason is none of these operations takes that much time... second since you are showing and hiding the element in the same thread the element will be hidden before browser get a chance to repaint it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work with timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 0.5 seconds
}, 500);
```

So the jquery code looks like this now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
        $('#notesunlimitedcontent').hide();
        $('#notescontent').show();

        $('a#nsetcontent').click(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#notesunlimitedcontent').hide();
            }, 500);
            $('#notescontent').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
            }, 500);
        });


        $('a#nusetcontent').click(function () {
            $('#loading').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#notescontent').
            }, 500);
            $('#notesunlimitedcontent').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
            }, 500);
        });

    });
</script>
```

To explain the animation I wanted, I have an div that has an transparent background and contains an image that shows an loading .gif. That should overlay the content that is changed.

But everybody thanks for the quick repsonses!

Answer (score 1):

`.show` and `.hide` are not animated unless you pass an optional argument as suggested by christian in comments.

To use a fading effect you could use `.fadeIn` and `.fadeOut`.
Which accepts an optional argument for `speed` (and accepts some constants like `slow`, `fast`).

Comment: The show/hide functions also allow you to pass in a duration parameter to animate (http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

`.hide(500);` and `.show(500);`

`.slideUp(500);` and .`slideDown(500);`

`.fadeOut(500);` and `.fadeIn(500);`

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
.show('slow');

.hide('slow');
```

OR

```
.fadeIn('slow');//instead of show()

.fadeOut('slow');// instead of hide
```

Instead of '`slow`', you can give numerical value also which will be taken as **milli seconds**.

For eg : `.show(1000)` and so on.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.show(5000);
.hide("slow");
```

Maybe that will let you see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this for modern browsers would be to use [css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) and then just explicitly change the elements' opacity. So instead if doing something like `$('#loading').show()` you can do `$('#loading').css('opacity', 1)` and if you wanted to hide the element you'd do the same thing except pass 0 for the second arg to css().

Then in your css file you may want to make a '.fadeable' class that you can reuse with different elements like so:

```
.fadeable {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms linear
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms linear
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms linear
    transition: opacity 500ms linear
}
```

Then just attach those classes to the elements you want to fade such as #loading and #notescontent. The advantage of using transitions over fadeIn()/fadeOut() is that you gain masive performance improvements  by using the browser's native animation engine, and it frees up the js timer to take care of other tasks it must perform manner rather than just having to execute animation events. If you need to support older browsers and IE9 however, it's a good idea to *fall back* to jQuery's animation methods.